# Not able to use Callable statement from Connection Pool from WLS 12.1.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource, connection-pooling, weblogic12c

I have created Datasource and try to get connection object using the below code,

```
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();         
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");            
        java.sql.Connection vendorConn = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
            javax.sql.DataSource ds
                    = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDataSource");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
             } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
             }
```

Below I have mentioned connection object and callable object,

```
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialConnection_weblogic_jdbc_rmi_internal_ConnectionImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection_12130_WLStub@d4
cstmt = (weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialCallableStatement_weblogic_jdbc_rmi_internal_CallableStatementStub_weblogic_jdbc_rmi_internal_CallableStatementImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper_12130_WLStub) weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialCallableStatement_weblogic_jdbc_rmi_internal_CallableStatementStub_weblogic_jdbc_rmi_internal_CallableStatementImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper_12130_WLStub@145
```

I am getting the below exception when i called a store procedure using callable

java.sql.SQLException: weblogic.rmi.extensions.RemoteRuntimeException:

```
Unexpected Exception
    at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialStatement.close(SerialStatement.java:126)
    at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialStatement.close(SerialStatement.java:110)

    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:451)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:375)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:310)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4855)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4529)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3976)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:120)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5375)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
java.sql.SQLException: prepareStatement, Exception = Unexpected Exception
    at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.RMIWrapperImpl.invocationExceptionHandler(RMIWrapperImpl.java:102)
    at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.RMIStubWrapperImpl.invocationExceptionHandler(RMIStubWrapperImpl.java:34)
    at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialConnection.prepareStatement(SerialConnection.java:236)


    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:451)
```

Please suggest is this the right way to use Datasource connection where all my sql statements are working but procedure is not getting called and also I need Is it required to typecast the SerialConnection to sql.Connection.

```
CallableStatement cst = null;
            try {
                cst = conn
                        .prepareCall("{call myProc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
                final String typeTableName = "studentdetails";

                cst.setInt(1, student.getEmpid());
                cst.setInt(2, student.getOrgid());
                cst.setInt(3, student.getYearid());
                cst.setString(4,  student.getClassType());
                cst.setInt(5, student.getStudentid());
                cst.registerOutParameter(6, Types.ARRAY, typeTableName);
                cst.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cst.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                                long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                cst.execute();
                                String dat=cst.getString(7);
                                 //Array arr = cst.getArray(6);
                                long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (null != cst.getObject(6)) {
                    data = (Object[]) ((Array) cst.getObject(6)).getArray();
                }
```

If I use datasource, I am  getting cst.getObject(6) as null, but if use normal jdbc connection it is working fine by providing the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Weblogic you must add the following element to your ***weblogic.xml***

```
<resource-description>
  <res-ref-name>datasource_ref</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/myDataSource</jndi-name>
</resource-description>
```

Then you must reference it from your deployment descriptor ***web.xml*** by adding following element

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>datasource_ref</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>    
</resource-ref>
```

Then you can reference your Data Src from your Java code like follows,

```
Context cntxt= (Context)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds= (DataSource)cntxt.lookup("datasource_ref");
```

Or by using **resource injection** like follows,

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DBHandler{
   @Resource(name="datasource_ref")
   private javax.sql.DataSource myDB;

   public Connection getConnection(){
      return myDB.getConnection();
   }
}
```

And you can use it on demand anywhere using CDI

```
DBHandler handler = CDI.current().select(DBHandler.class).get();
```

Or by field injection

```
@Inject
javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<DBHandler> instance;
....
void persist(){
    DBHandler handler=instance.get();
    Connection con= handler.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: Will this connection supports Store procedure call?

Comment: Yes. What we are doing here is simply burrowing a Connection from application server's connection pool. As long as application server's JDBC implementation supports Stored Procedure calls, any Connection burrowed from it should support the functionality.